# $watch for ng-model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

i have the following markup

```
<li ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
 <span>{{ticket.name}} - {{ticket.price}}</span>&nbsp;
 <input type="number" 
  value="1" 
  ng-disabled="!ticket.selected" 
  size="2" 
  style="width:34px;" 
  ng-change="ticket.quantity" 
 ng-model="ticket.quantity"/>
 <input type="checkbox" 
  name="choose" 
  ng-click="addToCart($event)" 
  ng-model="ticket.selected" 
  ng-if-false="false" 
  ng-if-true="true" 
  value="{{ticket.id}}"/>
</li>
```

then i have this on the addCart()

```
$scope.addToCart() = function(){ 

var template = '<fieldset id="ticket-'+this.ticket.id+'">' +
     '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'+$scope.counter+'" value="'+this.ticket.name+'">' +
     '<input type="hidden" name="amount_'+$scope.counter+'" value="'+this.ticket.price+'">' +
     '<input type="hidden" name="on0_'+$scope.counter+'" value="quantity">' +
     '<input type="hidden" name="os0_'+$scope.counter+'" value="'+this.ticket.quantity+'"></fieldset>',
     $el = angular.element('#payform').append(template).find('input[name=os0_' + $scope.counter +']');
     $scope.$watch(this.ticket.quantity,function(){
        console.log(this, 'this', arguments);
        console.log('ticket',ticket);
        console.log($el.attr('name'));
     })
     return false;
}
```

I'm trying to dynamically watch for changes in the passed model to update the dynamically created form elements.

How can I achieve this and how heavy is it to keep adding and removing the event if the element no longer exists?

Comment: You must pass to the $watch function the variable name, not the variable It self

Comment: ng-change takes a function as its argument `ng-change="doSomething()"`

Comment: this doesn't look like the angular way of achieving what you want.  Angular two way binding can update the DOM dynamically whenever the data changes, there is no need to manually create DOM elements.  put the template under an `ng-repeat`, and add or remove elements from the array the repeat is on.

Comment: AngularJS automatically monitors ng-model variables, so much of the code you've posted is unnecessary. You have a couple of problems in your code that I'll address anyhow. 1) you're referring to this.ticket as the ng-model variable, but the ticket variable exists in $scope and should be referred to as $scope.ticket. 2) your $watch is broken, as @Fals indicated, but you're again referring to this.ticket in the first parameter. It should be in the form $scope.$watch('ticket', function(){...}).

Comment: It seems like you're just getting started with Angular, so it could be worth watching the video playlist at https://youtu.be/WuiHuZq_cg4?list=PL173F1A311439C05D

Comment: @Fals  I think you may have mist understood my delima...the code posted happens INSIDE of the *$scope.addToCart* function. thanks for the tip

Comment: @sheppe *this.ticket* is reference to the instance inside of the addToCart function. I have tried the version code you suggested but it kept being undefined

Comment: @Kendall Makes no sense. $watch matchs variables inside scope by name, not by value.

Comment: @Claies I'm adding this stuff after the ng-repeat fact and its only based on user interaction

Comment: [have you tried this?](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Comment: @Fals ok great so I've got it wrong...if not $watch how do I listen to the model object referenced INSIDE the function that will update a dynamicaly created dom element on the fly then its property has changed?

Comment: @ODelibalta yes...the problem comes INSIDE the event handler

Comment: I am guessing this is probably what you do not want to hear this but based on what I am seeing here, you can achieve this easy with directives which is sort of what you are doing here in a very very basic level.

Comment: @Kendall I never suggested that it be in the same `ng-repeat`, but you definitely should use a different `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Kendall take a look at my awnsear and see if fits your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are heading in the hardest direction. You should add this template at your view using `ng-repeat`, not creating elements inside the controller, whats represent the worst pratice ever. You should add this tickets inside an array, `addedTickets` for exemple and let AngularJS do the hardest job: render it dinamically!

For Exemple:

**VIEW**

```
<input type="checkbox" 
 name="choose" 
 ng-click="addToCart(ticket, $index)" 
 ng-if-false="false" 
 ng-if-true="true" 
 ng-model="ticket.selected" />

<fieldset id="ticket-{{t.id}}" ng-repeat="t in addedTickets">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name_{{$index}}" ng-model="t.name">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount_{{$index}}" ng-model="t.price">
 <input type="hidden" name="on0_{{$index}}" ng-model="t.quantity">
</fieldset>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.addToCart(ticket, index) {
 if(ticket.selected) 
   $scope.addedTickets.push({name: ticket.name, quantit: ticket.quantity, /*etc*/});
 else
   //delete it
}
```

Comment: Hmm you don't say... adding the template to my view is not what I need. The template is added if and ONLY IF the related element is selected by the user. the template needs to also be dynamically removed if the user unselects the related element. I will look at adopting another approach. I'm all for "best practices"

Comment: @Kendall Yes, it will be added ONLY if has something inside the addedTickets array! You can provide the logic to delete if the user uncheck the check box, but, I gave the direction

Comment: @Kendall Did the hard job for you, checkout.the answer again

Comment: oohhh ok ok i get it now i get it...smh yes I'm so new to angular...but this should have been easy for veteran programmer like me to have figured it out...smh